# How to handle outside changes in react context?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am working on a personal project where the logged-in user will be provided by UserContext.js. I used JWT for frontend authentication.
Used Axios interceptor listener to handle interception.

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (res) => res,
  (err) => {
    if (err.response.status === 401) {
      axiosInstance
        .post("token/refresh/", {
          refresh: localStorage.getItem("refresh"),
        })
        .then((response) =>
          localStorage.setItem("access", response.data.access)
        )
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
    }
  }
);
```

everything works fine until jwt token expiry period. if it reaches expiry time then my 'UserContext' consumers return 401 (unauthorized) as 'access' value does not update in UserContext

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Component } from "react";
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { axiosInstance } from "../Services/ApiCalls";

export const UserContext = createContext({
  username: "",
  access: "",
  refresh: "",

  authorized: false,
  signin: () => {},
  signout: () => {},
});

export default class UserContextProvider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      access: localStorage.getItem("access"),
      refresh: localStorage.getItem("refresh"),
      username: "",
      authorized: "",
    };

    this.signout = this.signout.bind(this);
    this.signin = this.signin.bind(this);
  }

  signin = (username, password) => {
    axiosInstance.post("token/", { username, password }).then((response) => {
      this.setState(
        {
          access: response.data.access,
          refresh: response.data.refresh,
        },
        () => this.retrieve()
      );
      localStorage.setItem("access", response.data.access);
      localStorage.setItem("refresh", response.data.refresh);
    });
  };
  signout = () => {
    this.setState({ username: "", access: "", refresh: "", authorized: false });
    localStorage.removeItem("access");
    localStorage.removeItem("refresh");
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.retreive();
  }

  retrieve = () => {
    this.state.access &&
      axiosInstance
        .get("user/", {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${this.state.access}`,
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          this.setState({
            username: response.data.username,
            authorized: true,
          });
        });
  };
  render() {
    const { username, access, refresh, authorized } = this.state;
    const value = {
      username,
      access,
      refresh,
      authorized,
      signout: this.signout,
      signin: this.signin,
    };
    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={value}>
        {this.props.children}
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

if I use componentDidUpdate() and run this.retrieve() into it, it keeps sending request. so what's the best way to listen to changes in localStorage or what changes should I make to keep the user connected?

Comment: Not sure if this is the correct way to do it, but What I did is listen on error. Basically you get an error if the token is expired. The error only accures when you execute some sort of api fetch/post - whatever. With Axios (I see you using it) you can make a catch block - if an error accures it will execute the catch block. The error will contain a lot of information including a status code for the error. So you just have to check for 401 error. If so - log him out. My way would be if 401 - redirrect to logout page, where user is logged out, and after it redirrect him back to main page.

Comment: fyi, the catch block will go after `.then(()=>)` as `.catch((error) => ...`

Comment: I would advice to use a redirrect method rather then logging out the user on stop. It should be good practive to not fill everything into one component. User logging out should be his own seperate responsability - logging user out, redirrecting him, maybe even logging him back in if he has a refresh token valid. Basiclaly entire user logic should be seperate from whatever component recieved 401 error for a fetch. basically - single responsobility principle.